# please help me to show Hindi fonts on my asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, localization

please tell me how can i show matter in Hindi Language on my asp.net page. and the main thing is that my text should be visible even if the Hindi font is not installed at client side. for that i researched on Google and find out that unicode can do it.. but i dont know how to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes we can do it using nvarchar datatype to store data and then show it directly on page 
reference:

```
http://dotnetacademy.blogspot.com/2010/01/show-data-in-hindi-without-installing.html
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser can only display fonts that are installed on the users PC, and you can use the CSS font-face property to specify the font(s) that should be used.