# How to display Hindi font in asp.net web application with utf-8?

Tags: asp.net, json.net

I am working on a web application in `ASP.NET` using `Json` with `AJAX`, my requirement is that I want to display some text which is in `Hindi` language though my database contains that text in Hindi itself but output is shown as ??? for राम

Please put on your suggestions

Comment: So what's not working with what you've tried?

Comment: I am not getting output. Expected output is राम but I am getting ??? where this is an output text

Comment: Perhaps you might want to show us the code that's not working for you? It sounds like an encoding issue, but it's difficult to say, without seeing any of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The data stored in database must use Nvarchar datatype. You may have used different datatype .

Also check the links below for more details :

http://forums.asp.net/t/1534399.aspx?How+to+show+hindi+Malayalam+Text+in+Webpages+

[please help me to show Hindi fonts on my asp.net web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028187/please-help-me-to-show-hindi-fonts-on-my-asp-net-web-application)

Comment: I am using nvarchar as a data type and stored hindi text in the database but when show them on the webpage appears in ???